# "Unable to resolve module `events` in React Native using "cheerio"

Tags: react-native

I get this bug. After updating to RN 0.46.
[simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVvIu.png)

How to fix it?

Comment: Did you try the `npm start -- --reset-cache`? I've been seeing some of these similar errors occasionally and it's always worked for me.

Comment: nope, it does not make sense. There is an issue https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/issues/1058, they say that it can not work in RN, but in my other project "cheerio" works good with RN 0.42

Comment: seems to me it's a bug in new version of RN, or they changed something